# Laravel 4 Jquery Ajax Json data request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, laravel

I have a jquery ajax request:

```
  var settingsContainer = {};
  settingsContainer.font_family = $j("#supercontainer").css("font-family");


  var settingsContainerJson = JSON.stringify(settingsContainer);

  var BASE = "<?php echo Request::Root(); ?>/";
  return $j.ajax
  ({
  type: 'PUT',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: { settingsContainer: settingsContainerJson },
  url: BASE+'pages/update/{{ $page_id }}',
  success: function(data)
  { 
    alert(data);
  }
  });
```

This goes to my routing:

```
Route::put("/pages/update/{id}", array('as'=>'ajax', 'uses'=>'PageController@putSave'));
```

And that goes to my controller:

```
public function putSave($id) {
    $a = json_decode(Input::get('settingsContainer'));
    return $a['font_family'];
}
```

This currently does not return anything in Laravel 4. If I remove the dataType: json in my jquery call, it does return something, so it seems to break with the JSON data processing somehow. Suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Aren't you getting a 500 error or anything?

Comment: No, it just doesn't return anything. If I replace return $a['font_family'] with return $a, it outputs 2. I am staring a little bit too long at this I guess, but I thought I could access $a as if it was an array after decoding it...

Comment: try returning from your controller with the correct headers and JSON structure : `return Response::json(array($a['font_family']));`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using `PUT` in your `ajax` as the request method but `Laravel` uses `POST` for a `PUT` request and mimics the `PUT` request by sending a hidden field as:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
```

This is automatically generated/appended by `Form::open()` method in the form and since you are using `ajax` and `json`, you should add `_method:'PUT'` within your `data` and change the `type:'PUT'` to `type:'POST'` so it'll be available in the `$_POST` array and `Laravel` can do the work (As a PUT request). So, your `data` should be something like this:

```
{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { settingsContainer:settingsContainerJson, _method:'PUT' },
    // ...
}
```

Also check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) about PUT, DELETE etc methods and browser support.